# Executing a python file from PHP - Linux

Tags: php, python, linux

I have a python file that I would want to execute whenever a php page is called. The python file is in the same folder as the php file. The python script on execution edits a textfile that the php file accesses.

I have the following code:

```
<?php 
exec("python somefile.py",$output);
$file = fopen("test.txt",'r');
....
```

For some reason, the python script never gets executed. I know this certainly as I can see it from the changes in the text file.
Since I was not sure if the script was made executable, so I included "python" on the command. 
I also ran:

```
chmod +x somefile.py
```

just to make sure this was not the reason. But this did not help too.
What should I change to make the php page execute the python script whenever it is called?

Comment: Are you able to run `exec()`? Many times you'll find it in disabled functions for php.

Comment: have you tried `/usr/bin/python ...`? `$PATH` may not being available in web server environment

Comment: I am not sure if that is the case. As I see no errors when I load the php page. Is there a way to enable exec() function? Or is there a way around it?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` goes to the first line of the php script. reload the page, what are you seeing?

Comment: I still do not see any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a permission issue.

Try

```
echo exec("whoami");
```

This will let you know who php is running as. Then you need to verify this user can run the python script. If the file was not created by the same daemon that runs python, you will most likely be denied permission.

**Update**

This will let you know who owns all the files you are working with. The file being written to needs to be writable by the user that is running python. If you are running python from ssh, that is most likely not the same user as when you run python from exec.

```
echo exec('whoami') . "<br>";
echo exec("ls -l test.txt") . "<br>";
echo exec("ls -l somefile.py") . "<br>";
```

**Update 2**

Because I constantly forget this exists.

```
passthru('python somefile.py 1 2>&1');
```

This will exec your python file, and output stderr to stdout.

Comment: Can the apache user run the python script? And can the apache user write to the file?

Comment: I am not quite sure. I am new to linux and php. It could be very naive, but is Apache not the server? Does that have like a user account?
Throw some light on this please.

Comment: apache
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vicqa user1 3 Jul 15 10:46 test.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vicqa user1 522 Jul 2 10:08 somefile.py

This is what I get.

Comment: So it's a permission issue. chmod 777 test.txt and rerun your Php.